# Multiplex Akka sources/flows based on condition

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

Is there a way to multiplex two or more Akka sources or flows based on some external condition? It could look like this:

```scala
def cond: Boolean = ???

val src1 = Source.fromIterator(i1)
val src2 = Source.fromIterator(i2)
val src3 = Source.mux(src1, src2, cond)
```

Depending on `cond` result `src3` should contain either items from `src1` or items from `src2`, never both.

I have found what seems to be the opposite operation [`divertTo`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/divertTo.html). At the same time, none of the fan-in operations seem to support conditional merging.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you please add example input and desired output?

Comment: Not sure what additional example is needed. Supposing there are two independent sources of events, I want to combine them in such a way that only one of them is sent downstream, based on a dynamic condition which generally should be external to the events themselves.

Comment: Let's say `src1 = Source(1, 2, 3)`, and `src2 = Source(2, 3, 4)` and `cond = _ % 2 == 0` so `src3 = Source(2, 2, 4)` Do you expect something like that?

Comment: No. I mean, not necessarily. Condition does not have to depend on items in the source. Let's say, we have two independent infinite streams, A and B. And let's say, every day between 5 and 7 PM I want to receive only messages from stream A, and the rest of the day - from the stream B. In fact now that I think about it, perhaps one way to do it would be to zip each source with some id, then merge them and then filter the resulting source by this id. I am not sure if it is the right way though.

Comment: So please elaborate, as you did in your last comment, and create [mre] so we better understand how to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest something along the following:

```
def mux[T](a: Source[T, Any], b: Source[T, Any])(cond: Int => Boolean): Source[T, Any] = {
  a.map((1, _)).merge(b.map((2, _)))
    .filter(t => cond(t._1))
    .map(_._2)
}
```

Simply put, it attaches an identifier to the element emitted by each source (here 1, 2, but could be anything), then filters with the provided `cond` function to keep only the elements coming from the currently selected source, then maps back to the element.

I think `zip` is not a good idea because it *"Emits when all of the inputs have an element available"*, i.e. even if there is an element available from source A and you actually want to switch to source A, `zip` will wait until there is an element available in B before emitting ([ref](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.6/akka/stream/scaladsl/FlowOps.html)).

On the other hand, `merge` will emit immediately when any source has an available item.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking about in my other comment, and it is a valuable observation indeed that `zip` may be not quite right there. I just wondered if there was something out of the box for that, since multiplexing seems to be rather common operation. Also, could you elaborate why you used `via(flow)` instead of mapping directly on `Source`?

Comment: The `via(Flow)` is indeed silly - removed it! I am not experienced with Akka, another option seems to be [Source.combine](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.6/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source$.html#combine[T,U](first:akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[T,_],second:akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[T,_],rest:akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[T,_]*)(strategy:Int=%3Eakka.stream.Graph[akka.stream.UniformFanInShape[T,U],akka.NotUsed]):akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[U,akka.NotUsed]), but it looks more complex.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is what you need, but you can try the following:

```
def cond: Boolean = Random.nextBoolean()

val src1 = Source.fromIterator(() => LazyList.from(1).iterator)
val src2 = Source.fromIterator(() => LazyList.from(-1, -1).iterator)
val src3 = src1.zip(src2).map(pair => if (cond) pair._1 else pair._2)

src3.runForeach(println)
```

In one [run in Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/B24IOpEITz655ejsJYC15w/1), the output begins in:

```
1
-2
3
4
-5
-6
7
-8
-9
10
...
```

As you can see, in this example I randomly choose between the 2 streams.